# Цикл в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, циклы

Как в JavaScript сделать цикл...у меня много полей в таблице, а каждую если расписывать будет большой код.
Вот пример:

```
function tabl_igroki_1(){

    html='';
    html+='<tr>';
    html+='<td id="fignya1"></td>';
    html+='<td id="fignya2"></td>';
    html+='<td id="fignya3"></td>';
    html+='<td id="fignya4"></td>';
    html+='<tr>';

    $(html).appendTo('#tablica');

    $('#fignya1').click(function(){
        $('#fignya1').html('Из');
    })
    $('#fignya2').click(function(){
        $('#fignya2').html('базы');
    })
    $('#fignya3').click(function(){
         $('#fignya3').html('запись');
    })
    $('#fignya4').click(function(){
        $('#fignya4').html('игроки');
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

очень просто:

```
var data = {
    'fignya1': 'Из', 
    'fignya2': 'базы', 
    'fignya3': 'запись', 
    'fignya4': 'игроки'
};

for(var id in data){
    $('#'+id).click(function(){
        $(this).html(data[id]);
    });
}
```